# loadFromFile() not loading in sfml

Tags: c++, graphics, xcode4, sfml

I'm using sfml 2.1 in xcode4. ballSpriteSheet.png is in the project folder. It loads using a full file path. Why won't the file load as written? If not possible as written, can you at least set a relative path?

```
if(!tBall.loadFromFile("ballSpriteSheet.png"))
    std::cout << "ERROR: Could not load ball sprite sheet!" << std::endl;
```

In output...
Failed to load image "ballSpriteSheet.png". Reason : Unable to open file
ERROR: Could not load ball sprite sheet!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'ballSpriteSheet.png' must be in app Working Directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can not open and image using the SFML library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853838/i-can-not-open-and-image-using-the-sfml-library)

Answer (score 1):

The error reffer to the image that cannot be found. Please check the image to be in the project or to be next to your '.exe' and to be named correctly.