# C++ release program is unable to load images and font in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, sfml

I made a a pogram for my project but none of the images or the fonts load for some reason

the program runs just fine and the compiler doesn't say any error at all but when the program runs for release it is a black box

A snippet of my code:

```
VideoMode vm(1600, 1200);
    RenderWindow window(vm, "francais project", Style::Resize);

    Texture texturebackground;
    texturebackground.loadFromFile("graphics/white.png");
    Sprite background;
    background.setTexture(texturebackground);

    Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("fonts/cour.ttf");

    Text question;
    question.setFont(font);
    question.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    question.setCharacterSize(60);
    question.setPosition(50, 50);

    Text answer1;
    answer1.setFont(font);
    answer1.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    answer1.setCharacterSize(50);
    answer1.setPosition(200, 200);

    Text answer2;
    answer2.setFont(font);
    answer2.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    answer2.setString("2.voiture");
    answer2.setCharacterSize(50);
    answer2.setPosition(200, 300);

    Text answer3;
    answer3.setFont(font);
    answer3.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    answer3.setCharacterSize(50);
    answer3.setPosition(200, 400);

    Text answer4;
    answer4.setFont(font);
    answer4.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    answer4.setString("2.voiture");
    answer4.setCharacterSize(50);
    answer4.setPosition(200, 500);

    //for showing the score
    Text textScore;
    textScore.setFont(font);
    textScore.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    textScore.setCharacterSize(100);
    textScore.setPosition(100, 100);

    int intScore = 0;

    //bread textures

    Texture textureBread1;
    textureBread1.loadFromFile("graphics/bread1.png");

    Texture textureBread2;
    textureBread2.loadFromFile("graphics/bread2.png");

    Texture textureBaguette;
    textureBaguette.loadFromFile("graphics/baguette.png");

    Texture textureBread4;
    textureBread4.loadFromFile("graphics/bread4.png");


    //tower textures
    Texture textureTower1;
    textureTower1.loadFromFile("graphics/tower1.png");

    Texture textureEiffelTower;
    textureEiffelTower.loadFromFile("graphics/eiffel_tower.png");

    Texture textureTower3;
    textureTower3.loadFromFile("graphics/tower3.png");

    Texture textureTower4;
    textureTower4.loadFromFile("graphics/tower4.png");

    //tower sprites
    Sprite spriteTower1;
    Sprite spriteEiffelTower;
    Sprite spriteTower3;
    Sprite spriteTower4;

    spriteTower1.setTexture(textureTower1);
    spriteEiffelTower.setTexture(textureEiffelTower);
    spriteTower3.setTexture(textureTower3);
    spriteTower4.setTexture(textureTower4);

    spriteTower1.setPosition(300, 200);
    spriteEiffelTower.setPosition(1000, 200);
    spriteTower3.setPosition(300, 600);
    spriteTower4.setPosition(1000, 600);

    //brand textures
    Texture textureChanel;
    textureChanel.loadFromFile("graphics/chanel.png");

    Texture texturePerfume2;
    texturePerfume2.loadFromFile("graphics/perfume2.png");

    Texture texturePerfume3;
    texturePerfume3.loadFromFile("graphics/perfume3.png");

    Texture texturePerfume4;
    texturePerfume4.loadFromFile("graphics/perfume4.png");

    //brand sprites
    Sprite spriteChanel;
    Sprite spritePerfume2;
    Sprite spritePerfume3;
    Sprite spritePerfume4;

    //sets texture of perfumes
    spriteChanel.setTexture(textureChanel);
    spritePerfume2.setTexture(texturePerfume2);
    spritePerfume3.setTexture(texturePerfume3);
    spritePerfume4.setTexture(texturePerfume4);

    spriteChanel.setPosition(280, 200);
    spritePerfume2.setPosition(1000, 200);
    spritePerfume3.setPosition(300, 700);
    spritePerfume4.setPosition(1000, 650);

    //textures of brands

    Texture textureBrand1;
    textureBrand1.loadFromFile("graphics/brand1.png");

    Texture textureBrand2;
    textureBrand2.loadFromFile("graphics/brand2.png");

    Texture textureBrand3;
    textureBrand3.loadFromFile("graphics/brand3.png");

    Texture texturePaul;
    texturePaul.loadFromFile("graphics/paul.png");

    //brands sprites
    Sprite spriteBrand1;
    Sprite spriteBrand2;
    Sprite spriteBrand3;
    Sprite spritePaul;

    //sets texture of sprites
    spriteBrand1.setTexture(textureBrand1);
    spriteBrand2.setTexture(textureBrand2);
    spriteBrand3.setTexture(textureBrand3);
    spritePaul.setTexture(texturePaul);

    spriteBrand1.setPosition(280, 200);
    spriteBrand2.setPosition(1000, 200);
    spriteBrand3.setPosition(300, 700);
    spritePaul.setPosition(1000, 650);

    //texture flags
    Texture textureFlagFrance;
    textureFlagFrance.loadFromFile("graphics/flag_france.png");

    Texture textureFlag2;
    textureFlag2.loadFromFile("graphics/flag2.png");

    Texture textureFlag3;
    textureFlag3.loadFromFile("graphics/flag3.png");

    Texture textureFlag4;
    textureFlag4.loadFromFile("graphics/flag4.png");

    //flag sprites
    Sprite spriteFlagFrance;
    Sprite spriteFlag2;
    Sprite spriteFlag3;
    Sprite spriteFlag4;

    spriteFlagFrance.setTexture(textureFlagFrance);
    spriteFlag2.setTexture(textureFlag2);
    spriteFlag3.setTexture(textureFlag3);
    spriteFlag4.setTexture(textureFlag4);

    spriteFlagFrance.setPosition(300, 200);
    spriteFlag2.setPosition(300, 425);
    spriteFlag3.setPosition(300, 625);
    spriteFlag4.setPosition(300, 850);

    //bread sprites

    Sprite spriteBread1;
    Sprite spriteBread2;
    Sprite spriteBread3;
    Sprite spriteBread4;

    spriteBread1.setTexture(textureBread1);
    spriteBread2.setTexture(textureBread2);
    spriteBread3.setTexture(textureBaguette);
    spriteBread4.setTexture(textureBread4);

    spriteBread1.setPosition(300, 200);
    spriteBread2.setPosition(300, 400);
    spriteBread3.setPosition(300, 600);
    spriteBread4.setPosition(300, 800);

    Texture textureArrow;
    textureArrow.loadFromFile("graphics/Arrow.png");
    Sprite spriteArrow1;
    Sprite spriteArrow2;
    Sprite spriteArrow3;
    Sprite spriteArrow4;

    spriteArrow1.setTexture(textureArrow);
    spriteArrow2.setTexture(textureArrow);
    spriteArrow3.setTexture(textureArrow);
    spriteArrow4.setTexture(textureArrow);

    spriteArrow1.setPosition(100, 200);
    spriteArrow2.setPosition(100, 400);
    spriteArrow3.setPosition(100, 600);
    spriteArrow4.setPosition(100, 800);
```

I keep getting this error message in the terminal of the program not the compiler:

```
Failed to load image "graphics/white.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load font "fonts/cour.ttf" (failed to create the font face)
Failed to load image "graphics/bread1.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/bread2.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/baguette.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/bread4.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/tower1.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/eiffel_tower.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/tower3.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/tower4.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/chanel.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/perfume2.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/perfume3.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/perfume4.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/brand1.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/brand2.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/brand3.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/paul.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/flag_france.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/flag2.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/flag3.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/flag4.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "graphics/Arrow.png". Reason: Unable to open file
```

Comment: You're loading from relative paths (i.e., relative to the program's working directory). Either use full paths if possible, or have the program output the working directory and verify that the fonts/ and graphics/ subdirectories are in that working directory.

Comment: Are you using Windows and Visual Studio? If yes,  I hope I can formulate correct answer for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can not open and image using the SFML library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853838/i-can-not-open-and-image-using-the-sfml-library)

Comment: I apologize for not responding for a long time. I had a lot of homework and school projects to do. Though I did eventually fix it myself. The answer the from xX randomryze Xx did exactly what I did. thank you for your help. regret being too busy to check the answers and reading your reply as I had to do many stupid things for it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem I had when I first started working with SFML.
So the easiest way to get rid of these errors and load the files into your program is to add every file you want to load where your .exe or .cpp files Are . This is solution for the beginning but I still haven't got to the point where I need to replace the directory.
[image: Here is a picture of how it should look]

You can see that I have folders for my different files as you did, it's the same way, not the same place only(if that's the case).

But if it still doesn't work you may want to check if you have linked your .dll files correctly

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure graphics folder and fonts folder has same path with your generated executable file.