# SFML unable to open file

Tags: c++, sfml

I used SFML to create ARKANOID.
If I run in debug mode, it will run normally.
But when I run in Release mode, it can't read the image file.

In the Command window, the output is as follows:
Failed to load image "        ??       
"?    ". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "es/ball.png   ". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "es/ball.png       
"?    ". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to load image "es/ball.png       
"?    ". Reason: Unable to open file

I've tried the absolute path and I've tried the relative path.
And i also tired loadFromFile("images/ball");

please help me

Comment: Are the debug/release binaries located in different directories?

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853838/i-can-not-open-and-image-using-the-sfml-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can not open and image using the SFML library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853838/i-can-not-open-and-image-using-the-sfml-library)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the PNG file in the directory where main.cpp is located. You can put it in both the debug directory and the release directory. Also note the file extension in the directory (.png or .jpg) and edit the code.

Comment: The image file should be located relative to the location of the executable, not relative to the source file/s.

Answer (score -1):

Try pasting the image where the execution folder or where the compiler is example in codeblocks if you have MinGW then paste it "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin" and it will work

Comment: The compiler location has nothing to do with the problem considered here.